# Magento 2: Show pending payment order in store front

Tags: magento2, payment, order-status

When orders get created, we set it to pending payment status, because the $ amount is only authorized, and won't be processed & invoiced 2 days later (due to requirement)

However, pending payment does not show up on store front & I can't find a way to enable it to show in store front.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Click on **Assign status to state** button above (Stores > Order Status) and you'll be able to change that.

[image]

#### Important note for Pending Payments

If you have a "pending payment" status order, **Magento 2 will cancel the order automatically after 8 hours** if the payment status doesn't change.

To change that, go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Order Cron Settings and change the Lifetime to a greater value.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Magento, show those orders at **frontend** whose status's `Visible On Storefront` field value is  **YES**.

[image]

By default, the status**Pending Payment** 's  `Visible On Storefront` field value is  **NO**.

So you need to make this **NO** value to **YES**.

There are two way, You can enable this status to the visible list.

---

**First, run below query at the database for make** `Visible On Storefront` field value is  **YES**.

> Update  `sales_order_status_state` set visible_on_front =1  WHERE
>   `status`= 'pending_payment'

Comment: And the second way would be?